# googlemaps becomes extremely laggy after dialog overlay on it both for manual dragging/zooming

Tags: android, google-maps

**activity**

```
package com.demo.mapdialogdemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.demo.mapdialogdemo.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
    private Button btn;
    private View frame;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        showDialog();
        btn.setOnClickListener(v-> {
            showDialog();
        });
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = showCommonDialog(this);
    }

    public Dialog showCommonDialog(Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("test dialog");
        builder.setMessage("test dialog");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        WindowManager m = window.getWindowManager();
        Display d = m.getDefaultDisplay();
        lp.width = (int) (d.getWidth() * 0.95);
        // making area outside of the dialog can be touch.
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.5'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.mapdialogdemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

When I show a dialog overlay on my map fragment first time, things run well.Until I dissmiss the dialog and show it again, my maps becomes laggy on both for manual dragging/zooming.

Just like this kind of situation.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x9j1cvXZJ95hCsli7wVfEmocYauvJuiw/view

I wonder why it happens, and how can I solve it and make the map camera move smoothly.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a modal dialog and expect the map to still operate well. Dialogs are for [immediate user action](https://material.io/components/dialogs#usage). Under the hood, there is alpha compositing going on which isn't necessarily efficient.

Comment: You are right. It's not a good way to use a dialog for this kind of function, but I still wonder why it happens. There is another situation like video I provided in my question, a dialog show up overlay on the map and this dialog might just a immediate user action, however, it stills make things wierd, the map camera move so slow after it showed up.